# conditional expectation for Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose that $X_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter  $\lambda= 3$. Find $E(X_2 + X_4 | X_3)$?

I do not know how to approach this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You could start with $E(X_2+X_4|X_3) = E(X_2|X_3) +E(X_4|X_3)$. Next note that $X_4 = X_3+U$ where $U$ is the increment. This solves half of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you can determine the conditional distribution of $X_2$ given $X_3$ as follows: if $n \geq m$, then 
\begin{align}
& P[X_2 = m | X_3 = n]  \\
= & \frac{P(X_2 = m, X_3 = n)}{P(X_3 = n)} \\
= & \frac{P(X_2 = m, X_3 - X_2 = n - m)}{P(X_3 = n)} \\
= & \frac{P(X_2 = m)P(X_3 - X_2 = n - m)}{P(X_3 = n)} \quad \text{(by incremental independence)}\\
= & \frac{e^{-6}\frac{6^m}{m!} \times e^{-3}\frac{3^{n - m}}{(n - m)!}}{e^{-9}\frac{9^n}{n!}} \quad \text{(by } X_t - X_s \sim \text{ Poisson}(\lambda(t - s)))\\
= & \binom{n}{m}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^m\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n - m} , \quad m = 0, 1, \ldots, n.
\end{align}
If $n < m$, the conditional probability is $0$. Therefore, 
$$X_2 | X_3 \sim \text{Binomial}(X_3, 2/3),$$
which leads to $E[X_2 | X_3] = \frac{2}{3}X_3$. $E[X_4 | X_3]$ can be handled similarly.